# How to save the commands issued (only commands - not output) on a terminal session to a file for post-processing

Tags: bash, logging, scripting, command

I do a lot of my work on a terminal, issuing commands and producing files that I use as inputs for new commands etc... And, as I do this, I have a text editor open where I copy-paste the commands as I go along so that when I finish my work I can then save that file as a self-contained bash script that can be used if necessary to regenerate all my work from beginning to end.

I was wondering if there was a way of , when starting a terminal session issuing a command that would save all command from that point forward to a file (just the commands, not the output)

I have looked at script and that is way more complex than what I am trying to acheive.

I would just like to, in the end of issuing all the commands I needed I can then have a file I can open, remove duplicate or mistyped commands and add comments to properly document the entire process and then simply save it as a self contained bash script.

Comment: it's bash history you need - which stores all bash commands. The commands are stored in file referred to by HISTFILE environment variable.

Comment: yes... but history saves a lot more data with it like the timestamp  and I also have decided to keep my history accross terminals and I do not delete it So can can go back to any day in the past and sso all the commands...

So, if I have several terminal windows open , doing other things the commands get mixed.

Idealy I woud like to know of a way of kind of having a local hsitory file just for that session but also keeping the commnands going to the main history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working with bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Add this to your `~/.bashrc`, and as soon as you set `MYHIST=/path/to/my_history`, each command will be appended to that file until you set `MYHIST=`.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[ -n "$MYHIST" ] && history | tail -1 | awk "{ \$1=\"\"; print \$0 ; }" >> "$MYHIST"'
```

The `awk` expression strips the line number from the last history line.

Another way would be starting a new shell with a different history file and leaving it when you are done. However, this has the drawback that the commands will not appear in your normal history unless you explicitly append them:

```
HISTFILE=/tmp/myhist bash
command1
command2
^D
```

Comment: thanks @Michael Jaros .. this is closer to what I was looking for...
I just though that was already some ready-made utility in linux/unix to do it... I like the motto... do not reinvent the wheel... In this case I think we do need to invent something :)

Comment: I just tested your solution and it works like a charm...
I have changed it slightly because my history contains besides the line number a long timestamp

like:
50647  Sat 13 Sep 2014, 14:27:14:

so I altered your awk script to ignore the timestamp part:



PROMPT_COMMAND='[ -n "$MYPROTOCOL" ] && history | tail -1 | awk "{for(i=7;i<=NF;i++){printf \"%s \", \$i}; printf \"\n\"}" >> "$MYPROTOCOL"'

Answer (score 1):

History will give you the history of the commands from your current terminal session and you can just redirect it to an output file:

```
history >output-file
```

or

This will get the history file from the environment variable (for all sessions) and output it to a file:

```
grep -v "^#" $HISTFILE >all-output-file
```

Comment: Thanks @Donal .. Yes that works, but because I have decided to keep a really large history so that I have a record of past days, the history contains many more commands than I want, and because I do work on several terminals at the same time, the history will contain commands unrelated to the work on that specific terminal

Comment: the history command just gives you history from your current terminal session. so using this command will redirect the history of your current session to a file: history >output-file

Comment: well ... I am not sure what is different about my configuration because the history command gives me everything on my history file... and this means from august 15 2013.

Comment: Here are my relevant options on by .bashrc file related to the history:

export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
export HISTSIZE=100000
export HISTIGNORE=ls

shopt -s histappend
shopt -s histreedit
shopt -s histverify

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone and especially Michael.

I just tested his solution and it works like a charm...
I have adapted it slightly because my history contains besides the line number a long timestamp

like:
50647  Sat 13 Sep 2014, 14:27:14:

so I altered your awk script to ignore the timestamp part:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[ -n "$MYPROTOCOL" ] && history | tail -1 | awk "{for(i=7;i<=NF;i++){printf \"%s \", \$i}; printf \"\n\"}" >> "$MYPROTOCOL"'
```